# viewModel.setTitle(text) is a anti pattern in android?

Tags: android, viewmodel

developing app, I thought whether my viewModel.setTitle(text) is an anti patter or not.
I know the Ideal of a viewmodel is that doesn't know anything about the views.
But the View know the viewmodel.
So I tried that `var title = MutableLiveData<String>` in viewmodel, and the view set the title text like this `viewModel.setTitle(text)`
I want to know my using viewmodel.setTitle is an anti pattern or nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be a great understanding for you. If you're setting on a string on `observable it'll not breaking the pattern. Here is the detailed discussion regarding this [topic](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/viewmodels-and-livedata-patterns-antipatterns-21efaef74a54)

Answer (score 1):

So according to my knowledge, lets consider the responsibilities of each layer first

- View - Observes data in ViewModel and notifies UI event
- ViewModel - Presentation logic
- Model - Business logic

[image]

So view should be notifying the ui events to ViewModel, in your case view is actually asking the ViewModel to set the title.

So I have a suggestion, are you getting the title from an Intent, if yes then why not pass the bundle directly to ViewModel and let the ViewModel parse the data

```
viewModel.onCreate(bundle)
```

Since onCreate is an UI event we can use it in viewModel as well.
In your viewModel.onCreate your ViewModel can set title, fetch some initial data and do what is require to initialise the activity/fragment

If you are getting the title from server/backend i.e dynamic title, than I think your ViewModel can directly handle it

If your title is static and is set directly, then you should ask yourself is there a good reason to pass the title to your viewModel and set it from there, does it benefits you or is just creating boilerplate. If you are using it from strings.xml you can change it directly from strings file

So to answer your question is it an anti pattern, according to me yes. Why? instead of notifying UI event to viewModel, view is actually passing data to viewModel